# Q/A hide answers using jquery || elements not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a Q/A like page, but I'm having a couple problems with my code. I think it's something incredibly obvious but I can't spot it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Q/A </title>

    <style>
    #faqs dt, #faqs dd { padding: 0 0 0 50px }
    #faqs dt { font-size:1.5em; color: #9d9d9d; cursor: pointer; height: 37px; line-        height: 37px; margin: 0 0 15px 25px}
    #faqs dd { font-size: 1em; margin: 0 0 20px 25px}
    #faqs dt { background-color: red;) }
    #faqs .expanded { background-color: blue;)}
    </style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#faqs dd").hide();
$("#faqs dt").click(function () {
    $(this).next("#faqs dd").slideToggle(500);
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
});
</script>

<dl id="faqs">
<dt>Question 1</dt>
<dd>Answer 1</dd>

<dt>Question 2</dt>
<dd>Answer 2</dd>

<dt>Question 3</dt>
<dd>Answer 3</dd>
</dl>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/Xzw4U/, what's happening for you.  what browser?

Comment: Your code needs to be put inside a document ready call or placed at the end of the document. You're attempting to execute jQuery on elements that don't yet exist.

Comment: how are you running this?  If you're doing straight up file system this won't work because of the way you're including jquery.  Try changing it to ``https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js``

Comment: It takes ~30sec to load, and then goes to a static screen with the question and answers showing up (no toggle) on chrome

Comment: ahh, thanks. Forgot the document ready call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.next("dd")` instead of `.next("#faqs dd")` and wrap your code inside ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#faqs dd").hide();
    $("#faqs dt").click(function () {
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple!

Just add a CSS property `display:none` in your style script

```
#faqs dd { font-size: 1em; margin: 0 0 20px 25px; display:none}
```

Please add your jQuery script in document ready function

```
$("#faqs dd").hide();
$("#faqs dt").click(function () {
    $(this).next("#faqs dd").slideToggle(500);
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
});

});
```

Working jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3tjcb/)

Comment: This is also working solution, then why is a down vote, Please explain.